# Select rows from csv which have certain value

Tags: c#, linq, csv, filehelpers

I've got a problem with going through the CSV file, right now I'm using Filehelpers but I'm open to try any method which will give me an answer.

I have CSV file like this:

```
   001AD;1234;Window1;;;START;29-11-2016 07:32:00;;
   001AD;1234;Window1;;;STOP;29-11-2016 07:45:00;13;
   002BS;1222;;Frezowanie;;START;29-11-2016 07:53:00;;
   003MR;1243;Window2;;;START;30-11-2016 08:20:00;;
   002BS;1222;;Frezowanie;;STOP;30-11-2016 11:23:00;210;
   004DG;Oklejanie;;;;START;01-12-2016 06:33:00;;
```

And I want to select only those rows which has the same 3 first values, but don't have their "STOP" equivalent. So in this case it would've been line 4 and 6. Is there any option to do this?

Comment: that last line looks malformed or the rows are not uniform

Comment: Last line is like this, second way is having it like: 

004DG;;;Oklejanie;;START;01-12-2016 06:33:00;; if it changes anything

Comment: We need to see the code, and can make better suggestions about what to do next then.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't explicit your use case, I go with an SQLite solution :

first you'll have to [import your CSV file](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)

Then run the following query :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/689eb/10)

**SQLite (SQL.js) Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("a" TEXT(5), "b" TEXT(9), "c" TEXT(7), "d" TEXT(10), "e" INTEGER, "f" TEXT(5), "g" TEXT(19), "h" INTEGER)
;

INSERT INTO t
    ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
VALUES
    ('001AD', '1234', 'Window1', NULL, NULL, 'START', '29-11-2016 07:32:00', NULL)
;
-- ...
```

**Query 1**:

```
select sta.*
from (
        select * 
        from t 
        where f = "START"
    ) sta
LEFT JOIN (
        select * 
        from t 
        where f = "STOP"
    ) sto
    ON (
        sta.a = sto.a 
        OR (
            sta.a IS NULL 
            AND sto.a IS NULL
            )
        )
    AND (
        sta.b = sto.b 
        OR (
            sta.b IS NULL 
            AND sto.b IS NULL
            )
        )
    AND (
        sta.c = sto.c 
        OR (
            sta.c IS NULL 
            AND sto.c IS NULL
            )
        )
WHERE 
    sto.f IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/689eb/10/0)**:

```
|     a |         b |       c |      d |      e |     f |                   g |      h |
|-------|-----------|---------|--------|--------|-------|---------------------|--------|
| 003MR |      1243 | Window2 | (null) | (null) | START | 30-11-2016 08:20:00 | (null) |
| 004DG | Oklejanie |  (null) | (null) | (null) | START | 01-12-2016 06:33:00 | (null) |
```